# replay attack mitigation using onelogin php toolkit

Tags: php, saml, onelogin, replay

In the php SAML toolkit from onelogin dot com the README.md states:

"### Replay attacks ###

In order to avoid replay attacks, you can store the ID of the SAML messages already processed, to avoid processing them twice. Since the Messages expires and will be invalidated due that fact, you don't need to store those IDs longer than the time frame that you currently accepting.

Get the ID of the last processed message/assertion with the `getLastMessageId/getLastAssertionId` methods of the Auth object."

In my environment $auth->getLastRequestID() returns a good looking unique value, but getLastMessageId and getLastAssertionId both return nothing.

Is getLastRequestID sufficient to implement the described replay attack mitigation?